# Peer to peer replication in SQL Server 2005/08

Tags: sql-server, replication

Has anyone had any experience in setting up [peer to peer replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151196.aspx) using SQL Server 2005 or 2008?

Specifically, I'm interested in whether other options/alternatives where considered and why P2P replication was ultimately chosen.

If you have used P2P replication:

Did you encounter any issues during synchronization and was it easy to monitor?

How easy was/is it to do conflict resolution?

Did you have to make schema changes (i.e. replace identity columns, etc)?

Alternatively, if you considered P2P replication and went with a different option, why did you rule it out?

Comment: Rob - did you ever set up peer to peer replication, or get a better response (Peter's response touched on his experience with Merge replication, not P2P)

Comment: Unfortunately, no!  I was really quite keen to get feedback/experiences because I've not seen P2P Replication in a production environment (yet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I'm a developer, not a DBA)

We have SQL Server 2005 merge replication set up to replicate between two active/active geographically-separated nodes for resilience in a legacy system.

I don't know whether it's easy to monitor; outside of my remit.

It creates triggers on every table to do the publish/subscribe mechanism, each of which calls its own stored procedure.

In our case, it was set up to use identities 1-1bn in node 0, 1bn-2bn in node 1 to avoid identity collisions (rather than use a composite key of NodeId + EntityId for each table, or change keys to be GUIDs, for example).

I think the replication latency is around 15s (between London and New York over dedicated bandwidth).

It is a **huge pain to work with**:

- It took a highly paid contractor a year to set it up (granted, part of this was due to the legacy nature of the DB design)
- We lack anyone in-house with the expertise to support it (the in-house DBA we had took ~6 months to learn it, and has since moved on)
- Schema updates are now **painful**.  From what I understand:

  - Certain updates must be performed on only one node; replication then takes care of figuring out what to do on the other node(s)
  - Certain updates must be performed on both nodes
  - Data updates must be performed on one node only (I think)
  - All updates now take significantly longer to perform - from the split-second it takes to run a DDL change-script to ~30 minutes
- I don't know for sure, but I think the bandwidth requirement for replication is very high (in the MBit/s range)
- It introduces **many** "noise" objects (3 sprocs per table, 3 triggers per table) into the DB, making it inconvenient to find in the object explorer the item that one wants to work on.
- We will **never** set up a third node for this system, based largely on the perceived difficulty and added pain it would introduce at deployment-time.
- We also now lack a staging environment that mirrors production, because it's too painful to set up.
- Anecdotal: The DBA doing the setup would frequently curse the fact that it was an "MS v1" he was being forced to work with.
- Dimly remembered: The DBA needed to raise several priority support tickets to get help from MS directly.

Granted - some of the pain involved is due to our specific environment and not having in-house talent to support this setup.  Your mileage may vary.

Comment: (PTP replication has nothing to do with merge replication. It works with transactionnel rep, where all servers are publishers/subscribers). I am really surprised by yr comments on merge replication, schema updates and bandwidth issues. Can you confirm it, or are these just things you've heard?

Comment: These are issues I have to help deal with during 5am usage-ebb-time deployments.

(Thanks for clarifying PTP vs merge replication; I hadn't realised they were two different things.)